# Как регуляркой убрать пробелы между скобкой и точкой?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть такая строка

```
aaa) bbb) . ccc) , ddd
```

Нужно убрать все пробелы между скобкой с запятой и между скобкой и точкой. Сделал такую регулярку:

```
preg_replace('/\)\s(.|,)/si', ')$1', $input_lines);
```

Но она помимо нужных пробелов убирает **пробел и после первой скобки**, хотя регулярка говорит, что там должен быть еще один символ: точка или запятая.

```
aaa)bbb). ccc), ddd
```

Как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тебе нужно заэскейпить ещё и точку. `\)\s+(\.|,)` должно получится что-то такое. Ибо `.`, это любой символ.